# How to increase the dimensions of react-datepicker calender?

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

How can i increase the width and height of the calender popup. I checked there documentation and github pages nothing shows how to increase the width and height.
i am using react-datepicker for calender

i have given width and height to "react-datepicker-popper"

```
.react-datepicker-popper{
  width: "500px";
  height: "500px";
}
```

and also other internal classes but nothing works. is there any way to achieve this

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the double-quotes are not needed to while mentioning the CSS units. This should be the correct CSS declaration:

```css
.react-datepicker-popper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

**References:**

`height` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height

`width` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width

Comment: still not working